# fail2ban statistics?

Tags: debian, fail2ban

Is there a program that parses *fail2ban.log* and produces some statistics? Or should I set out and write something custom for our hosts? We run mostly Debian and fail2ban with iptables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [this](http://code.google.com/p/linuxplayer/source/browse/scripts/fail2ban-stat.pl?spec=svn0a4c88307df06e862d3e0c8ff0c7bab3200a51d0&r=0a4c88307df06e862d3e0c8ff0c7bab3200a51d0) in Google code and it does give some initial statistics per date and service. You can at least use it as a template to get the stats you want

Answer (score 0):

for graph stat you can use munin:

[image]

https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin